# How to avoid storing passwords in selenium script?

Tags: selenium

When storing selenium script the password is visible. how to avoid storing passwords and continue the script?

Answer (score 0):

Fearing of password/sensitive info being visible, then i would recommend to store sensitive info in external file (XML,Properties,txt etc) and then read it back rather than hard coding in script.

So Whenever you wish to run the script, just provide the file (which includes sensitive info).

Answer (score 0):

I use xdt transforms per environment and per user.

How you distribute the xdt's is up to you - normally i use svn externs where only the CI user can download metadata folder.

locally developers have a local xdt transform specific to their environment.